# How do I remove all but one specific duplicate record in an R data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that contains some duplicate ids.  I want to remove records with duplicate ids, keeping only the row with the maximum value.

So for structured like this (other variables not shown):

```
id var_1
1 2
1 4
2 1
2 3
3 5
4 2
```

I want to generate this:

```
id var_1
1 4
2 3
3 5
4 2
```

I know about unique() and duplicated(), but I can't figure out how to incorporate the maximization rule...

Comment: It should actually be in stackoverflow as it is a purely programming related task and has little to do with statistics

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One way is to reverse-sort the data and use `duplicated` to drop all the duplicates.
For me, this method is conceptually simpler than those that use apply. I think it should be very fast as well.

```
# Some data to start with:
z <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,4),var=c(2,4,1,3,5,2))
# id var
#  1   2
#  1   4
#  2   1
#  2   3
#  3   5
#  4   2

# Reverse sort
z <- z[order(z$id, z$var, decreasing=TRUE),]
# id var
#  4   2
#  3   5
#  2   3
#  2   1
#  1   4
#  1   2

# Keep only the first row for each duplicate of z$id; this row will have the
# largest value for z$var
z <- z[!duplicated(z$id),]

# Sort so it looks nice
z <- z[order(z$id, z$var),]
# id var
#  1   4
#  2   3
#  3   5
#  4   2
```

Edit: I just realized that the reverse sort above doesn't even need to sort on `id` at all. You could just use `z[order(z$var, decreasing=TRUE),]` instead and it will work just as well.

One more thought... If the `var` column is numeric, then there's a simple way to sort so that `id` is ascending, but `var` is descending. This eliminates the need for the sort at the end (assuming you even wanted it to be sorted).

```
z <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,4),var=c(2,4,1,3,5,2))

# Sort: id ascending, var descending
z <- z[order(z$id, -z$var),]

# Remove duplicates
z <- z[!duplicated(z$id),]
# id var
#  1   4
#  2   3
#  3   5
#  4   2
```

Comment: This approach is significantly faster than "split-compute-rbind". Furthermore it allows grouping on more than one factor. For a c. 650,000 row (8, narrow, columns) the "order-duplicated" approach took 55 seconds, the split-compute-rbind... 1h15minutes.  Of course when the aggregate computation is other than selecting or filtering duplicates, the latter approach or similar plyr-based approaches are needed.

Answer (score 7):

You actualy want to select the maximum element from the elements with the same id. For that you can use `ddply` from package **plyr**:

```
> dt<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,4),var=c(2,4,1,3,4,2))
> ddply(dt,.(id),summarise,var_1=max(var))
   id var_1
1  1   4
2  2   3
3  3   4
4  4   2
```

`unique` and `duplicated` is for removing duplicate records, in your case you only have duplicate ids, not records.

**Update:** Here is the code when there are additional variables:

```
> dt<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,4),var=c(2,4,1,3,4,2),bu=rnorm(6))
> ddply(dt,~id,function(d)d[which.max(d$var),])
```

Comment: What if there were other variables: how do you carry them along?

Comment: We don't move such questions -- too much rush for too little gain.

Answer (score 6):

The base-R solution would involve `split`, like this:

```
z<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,4),var=c(2,4,1,3,4,2))
do.call(rbind,lapply(split(z,z$id),function(chunk) chunk[which.max(chunk$var),]))
```

`split` splits the data frame into a list of chunks, on which we perform cutting to the single row with max value and then `do.call(rbind,...)` reduces the list of single rows into a data frame again.

Comment: And as usual this is about 2x faster than plyr version.

Comment: @mbq, yes, naturaly, but if you include the debugging costs, for usual data sets the resulting speed is the same :) **plyr** is dedicated not for speed, but for clarity and convenience.

Comment: and using ave is twice as fast anyway :)

Comment: @Eduardo `ave` is a wrapper of `lapply`+`split`, check the code (-;

Comment: @mbq ops! but subsetting does seem to be much faster than rbinding the results

Comment: @Eduardo Yeah, but it all works only due to a quirky possibility of vectorized sorting within factors using `order`; for more generic problems `split` is inevitable.

Comment: @mpq I think this is a quite common operation. I use it quite frequently. It is expressive and vectorized, what's not to like :)

Answer (score 5):

I prefer using `ave`

```
dt<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,4),var=c(2,4,3,3,4,2))
## use unique if you want to exclude duplicate maxima
unique(subset(dt, var==ave(var, id, FUN=max)))
```

Comment: +1, did not know about ave. When did it appear in R?

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do this with base:

```
dt<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,4),var=c(2,4,1,3,4,2))

data.frame(id=sort(unique(dt$var)),max=tapply(dt$var,dt$id,max))
  id max
1  1   4
2  2   3
3  3   4
4  4   2
```

I prefer mpiktas
' plyr solution though.

Answer (score 1):

If, as in the example, the column var is already in ascending order we do not need to sort the data frame. We just use the function `duplicated` passing the argument `fromLast = TRUE`, so duplication is considered from the reverse side, keeping the last elements:

```
z <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,4),var=c(2,4,1,3,5,2))
z[!duplicated(z$id, fromLast = TRUE), ]

  id var
2  1   4
4  2   3
5  3   5
6  4   2
```

Otherwise we sort the data frame in ascending order first:

```
z <- z[order(z$id, z$var), ]
z[!duplicated(z$id, fromLast = TRUE), ]
```

Using the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
z %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(var = max(var))

Source: local data frame [4 x 2]    
  id var
1  1   4
2  2   3
3  3   5
4  4   2
```